# Is is possible to set up a static IP through Pfsense when user is connecting through OpenVpn?

Tags: openvpn, static-ip, pfsense

I'm setting IP based restrictions on our firewall and need to allow certain people to connect even when they are connected through OpenVPN. Is it possible to assign users a static IP?

Comment: To clarify, you have a user that is trying to connect through the firewall to open VPN, and you need their public IP to be static? Or they're already connected to OpenVPN, and you need the internal IP assigned by OpenVPN to be static?

Comment: User is connecting remotely through OpenVPN to our network. I'm trying to set them up with a static IP so that I can block and allow certain people to various parts of our network through Pfsense.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by bridging the OpenVPN network device with the LAN network device, and then I disabled OpenVPN's DHCP server and let pfSense assign the IPs directly. This allowed me to configure static leases in pfSense for the computers, which were then given out to clients connecting over OpenVPN when they connected.

It's been a year since I was last messing with this (I've since moved to a simpler setup), but at the time the pfSense webconfig did not support putting OpenVPN into bridging mode, and I had to accomplish such by configuring it manually.

Comment: Actually the ISP wouldn't need to do that since the user is already on our network through OpenVpn. We are talking about static private IP.

Comment: Oh! Editing answer...